# Coupled PDEs with different dimensions and boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

The geometry of the problem is described by a cylinder inside a rectangular domain. The equations describes the region in between them.

[image]

I have 2 PDEs for U(x,y,z) in the bulk region and V(z) for -0.5<=z<=0.5 on the cylindrical surface:

[image]

with some Dirichlet B.C.s that are fine and a flux B.C.,
[image]

I am solving it using FEM and NDSolveValue, and not sure how to implement the 2nd equation, which involves a boundary flux from U to V at the cylindrical surface. I was looking at using Assuming or NeumannValue for the 2nd equation and the flux B.C. but there is no success. Could you share some opinions on these kinds of situations? Thanks!

```
Remove["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
x0 = 3; y0 = 3; z0 = 3;(*simulation size*)
cellsize = 0.05;
l = 1; r0 = 1;

With[{inner = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -l/2}, {0, 0, l/2}}, r0], 
   outer = Cuboid[{-x0, -y0, -z0}, {x0, y0, z0}]}, (mesh = 
    ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[outer, inner], 
     MaxCellMeasure -> cellsize])];

pdes = {Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
   D[v[z], {z, 2}] + 
     Assuming[x^2 + y^2 == 1, 
      D[u[x, y, z], x]/x + D[u[x, y, z], y]/y] == 0};
bcs = {
   NeumannValue[u[x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 == 1 && z > -l/2 && z < l/2] == 
 Assuming[z > -l/2 && z < l/2, v[z]],
  DirichletCondition[v[z] == 0, z <= -l/2 || z >= l/2],
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, 
   x^2 + y^2 < r0^2 && z >= -l/2 && z <= l/2], 
  DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 1, 
   x == x0 || x == -x0 || y == -y0 || y == y0 || z == -z0 || 
    z == z0]};

sol = NDSolveValue[{pdes, bcs}, {u[x, y, z], 
    v[z]}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];

ContourPlot[u[x, 0, z] /. sol, {x, -x0, x0}, {z, -z0, z0}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 AspectRatio -> z0/x0, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: This part is unclear `NeumannValue[u[x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 == 1 && z > -l/2 && z < l/2] == 
 Assuming[z > -l/2 && z < l/2, v[z]]`. In your picture there is $U(x,y,z)=V(z)$ at $x^2+y^2\rightarrow 1$. Please pay attention that   `NeumannValue` should be implemented in the right part of PDE as follows            `-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] ==NeumannValue[...]`